# How should I pass 32-bit arguments to Linux syscalls on x86_64?

Tags: linux, x86, syscalls

If a syscall needs some 32-bit arguments like `uid_t` or `int` (for file descriptors) or `unsigned int` or even some 16-bit type, how can I pass them using 64-bit registers?

Do I need to zero-extend or sign-extend them to 64-bit before I use the `syscall` instruction?

What if I use `__X32_SYSCALL_BIT` in RAX so the original 64-bit pointer-type argument becomes 32-bit, I still need to use the same 64-bit register to pass the argument, do I need to zero-extend address arguments in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You‘re supposed to zero-extend them, but for the common case of 32-bit values on x86-64, there’s no need to think about it: storing a value in a 32-bit register results in a zero-extended store to the corresponding 64-bit register (*i.e.*, `movl $4, %edx` stores 4 in `rdx`). 8- and 16-bit values should be explicitly zero-extended (`movzbl` or `movzwl` from an 8- or 16-bit register to a 32-bit register, implicitly zero-extending to 64 bits).

In practice, for non-pointers, the system call implementation will only read the lower *n* bits anyway, so you shouldn’t see any practical difference, at least for 32-bit values. (*E.g.* calling `SYS_read` with rubbish in the top 32 bits of `RDI` doesn’t produce an error, and only takes the lower 32 bits into account.) I haven’t checked what happens if you set `__X32_SYSCALL_BIT` without clearing the top 32 bits of pointers.

Comment: What if I don't zero-extend them? Will I get `-ENIVAL` (32bit two's complement represention in %eax and zero-extended to 64bit) returned in %rax? Are such returned 32-bit value in %rax  are guaranteed to be zero-extended?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 my tests suggest you won’t get an error. Return values are supposed to be interpreted according to their type’s size; if a system call returns in `int`, you can’t read all of `RAX` and consider that it’s the correct value. In practice they are zero-extended.